# Converting hash values to integers

Tags: ruby

I have a small program that creates a hash and stores the current datetime, where the year, month, and day are stored as separate values. This requires me to convert the `Time` object into a `String` object, but I would like to store the values as `Integer` objects for later comparison.

```
current = {}

current[:year], current[:month], current[:day] = Time.now.to_s[0..10].split('-')
```

I achieved this by writing the following code:

```
current.map { |key, value| current[key] = value.to_i }
```

However, I noticed that `Ruby 2.4.0` comes with a neat method for destructively transforming hash values, allowing me to pass a proc as an argument:

```
current.transform_values!(&:to_i)
```

My question is: *how would you go about writing the equivalent of the previous line of code in earlier versions of Ruby?* I ask because I think the map method becomes unnecessarily long.

Comment: There's a _reason_ it was added :)

Comment: [Array#map!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21) would be comparable to `transform_values`. Another way is `current.update(current) {  |_,o,_| o.to_i }`. This uses the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21) (aka `merge!`) which employs a block to compute the values of all keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which is here all keys. I think using `map!` here is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution for the given case**

If you want integers, why not use the `Time` object's built-in methods instead of creating strings?

```
t = Time.now

current = {year: t.year, month: t.month, day: t.day}
```

Now they're all integer values.

**Re-implementation**

Alternatively, you can implement the method yourself, as Rails does:

```
class Hash
  def transform_values!
    return enum_for(:transform_values!) unless block_given?
    each do |key, value|
      self[key] = yield(value)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: For this particular program, your solution is probably the most elegant one and I thank you for that. However, I was more interested in the general idea of transforming hash values in place.

Comment: I accept the answer where you show how to implement the `transform_values!` method. It will probably be my best option, because as you said, there is a reason this method was implemented in Ruby `2.4.0`.